# Populating a TextBox from an active row in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CmdBtnOpen_Click()
Dim rng1 As Range

Set rng1 = Sheets("MAIN").Range("B:B").Find(CStr(TxtBoxFUZEProjectID.Value), [B100000], xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlNext)

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "FUZE Project ID Found, form updated.", vbInformation
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = rng1.row
    CmbBoxHardwareVerified.Text = rng1.Cells()
Else
    MsgBox "FUZE Project not found. Do you want to import from FUZE Dump?", vbYesNo
    
End If

End Sub
```

So what I want to do is populate my

`CmbBoxHardwareVerified.Text` with the cell from the active row `(rng1.row)`, that cell being `Q` in this case.

And I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: TextBox or ComboBox

Comment: `CmbBoxHardwareVerified.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.Row,"Q").value`

Comment: If it is a TextBox, try `CmbBoxHardwareVerified.Text = rng1.Offset(0,15).Value`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CmdBtnOpen_Click()
Dim rng1 As Range

Set rng1 = 
Sheets("MAIN").Range("B:B").Find(CStr(TxtBoxFUZEProjectID.Value), [B100000], xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlNext)

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "FUZE Project ID Found, form updated.", vbInformation
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = rng1.row
TxtBoxMDGLocationCode.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "H")
TxtBoxeNodeB.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "C")
TxtBoxSiteName.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "D")
TxtBoxJobNumber.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "A")
CmbBoxHardwareVerified.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "Q")
CmbBoxConquestVerified.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "R")
CmbBoxCDU_ENV.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "S")
CmbBoxFSU_ENV.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "T")
CmbBoxRETFileReceived.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "U")
CmbBoxCutoverMethod.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "V")
CmbBoxCDUGrown.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "X")
CmbBoxFSUGrown.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "Y")
CmbBoxCellsGrown.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "Z")
CmbBoxFSUFMValidation.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AB")
CmbBoxCDUFMValidation.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AA")
CmbBoxCDUPostXmlRun.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AC")
CmbBoxCDURebooted.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AD")
CmbBoxRRHFirmwareUpdated.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AE")
CmbBoxValidateCDUCPRI.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AF")
CmbBoxValidateFSUCPRI.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AG")
CmbBoxValidateTraffic.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AI")
CmbBoxCDUPostCheck.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AJ")
CmbBoxFSUPostCheck.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AK")
CmbBoxEOSCompleted.Text = Sheets("MAIN").Cells(rng1.row, "AL")
Else
MsgBox "FUZE Project not found. Do you want to import from FUZE Dump?", vbYesNo

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The above worked well for me.